# Retrieve Api and render flatlist

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I have my own created Api that already on server :(http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications)
 When i retrieve it it only show my header name below are my code

```
  _load() {
    let url = 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications';

    this.setState({isFetching: true});

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Error', response.status.toString());
        throw Error('Error ' + response.status);
      }

      return response.json()
    })
    .then((members) => {
      this.setState({members});
      this.setState({isFetching: false});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

Rest of my code due stack cannot put all the code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwT4c.jpg

Comment: Can you show how your error message looks like ?

Comment: have you tried using at least `console.log(response)` or `console.log(members)` just to see what you are really getting?

Comment: Yes i use console log, there is no error only that it only show my header title and loading circle

Comment: I get the feeling that you should assign `response.data` to `members` instead. also, it is bad practice to do multiple `setState` in react.

Comment: @jegtugado do i need to add "data" in my   this.setState({ data: json.data }) because when i check my api got data object "http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications"

Comment: You should know what you need from *your* api. I'm just assuming you need `this.setState({ members: response.data })` after you convert `response` to `response.json()`.